# NSView distorted after NSWindow resized

Tags: macos, swift, nsview, nswindow, animator

I'm using the `animator()` to scroll a `NSScrollView` sideways between frames (child views) of my app. When the animation is happening and I resize the `NSWindow` the whole `NSView` gets distorted like so:

[image: NSView gets distorted during NSWindow resize]

Here's the code responsible for the transition:

```
func goToFrame(frameNumber: Int) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        var clipView: NSClipView = self.container.contentView
        newOrigin: NSPoint = clipView.bounds.origin
        newOrigin.x = CGFloat(self.viewWidth * frameNumber)

        NSAnimationContext.beginGrouping()
        NSAnimationContext.currentContext().duration = 0.4
        self.container.contentView.animator().bounds.origin = newOrigin
        self.container.reflectScrolledClipView(self.container.contentView)
        NSAnimationContext.endGrouping()
    })
}
```

Any idea why it would do that? I don't get any warnings in the log.

Comment: Not sure, but: `self.container.contentView.animator().bounds.origin = newOrigin` is not the same thing as `self.container.contentView.animator().setBoundsOrigin(newOrigin)`. Since bounds is an `NSRect`, what you've done is like `var bounds = self.container.contentView.animator().bounds ; bounds.origin = newOrigin ; self.container.contentView.animator().bounds = bounds`. The animation of setting the whole bounds rect may be different than just setting the origin. Also, you're calling `reflectScrolledClipView(_:)` before the change of bounds has taken effect, since that change is being animated.

Comment: Thanks Ken, it .setBoundsOrigin() worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Ken Thomases in a comment:

This line:

```
self.container.contentView.animator().bounds.origin = newOrigin
```

should be changed to:

```
self.container.contentView.animator().setBoundsOrigin(newOrigin)
```